# Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? One test case is failing

Tags: python, leap-year

```
def is_leap(year):
    leap = False
    
    # Write your logic here
    if year%4==0:
        return True
    elif year%400==0:
        return True
    elif year%100 != 0:
        return False
    else:
        return False
    return leap


year = int(input())
print(is_leap(year))
```

It is showing that one test case is failing.

Comment: How would you ever reach `year%400 == 0` check and have it be True if `year%4 == 0` check wasn't True? Every number divisible by 400 is also divisible by 4.

Comment: Wondering if `year %400` is not redundant. Secondly, you didn't specify which is failing.  Recommendation: perhaps first write in algorithm as algorithm and then put as Python code

Comment: @semmyk-research it's not with properly written conditions, as years divisible by 100 are not leap years unless they are also divisible by 400.

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention to the order. Your code second condition `year%400==0` cannot ever be reached, as anything that can be divided by 400 can also be divided by 4. Hence, every multiplication of 400 would have already been caught in the `year$4==0` condition

```py
def is_leap(year):
    if year % 400 == 0:
        return True
    if year % 100 == 0:
        return False
    if year % 4 == 0:
        return True
    return False
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that conditions are evaluated in the order they are written.

```
if year%4==0:
    return True
```

Every year divisible by four is a leap year...

```
elif year%400==0:
    return True
```

and every year divisible by 400 is also divisible by four, so this condition is never evaluated

```
elif year%100 != 0:
    return False
```

All other years not divisible by 100 are not leap years.

```
else:
    return False
```

And everything else is also not a leap year.

There is no point in having these two last cases; `if condition: return False else: return False` is equivalent to `return False`.

In summary: your conditional is equivalent to

```
if year%4==0:
    return True
else:
    return False
```

or simply `return year % 4 == 0`.
I hope you agree that this is incorrect.

Let's define a leap year.

The year X is a leap year if

- It is divisible by four,
- unless it is divisible by 100,
- except if it is divisible by 400

That is,

```
return x % 4 == 0 and not (x % 100 == 0 and not (x % 400 == 0))
```

which we can simplify,

```
return x % 4 == 0 and not (x % 100 == 0 and x % 400 != 0))
```

One of DeMorgan's laws: `not (a and b) == (not a) or (not b)`:

```
return x % 4 == 0 and (x % 100 != 0 or x % 400 == 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, your use of `if` and `elif` in the order you have, renders `year%400==0` redundant. The `if year%4==0` will be true, and the test condition stops.

I'll recommend you start with an algorithm and flowchart, then put in python code.

So, what's a leap year?
[Wikipedia!] A year that is an integer multiple of 4 (except for years evenly divisible by 100, but not by 400)

Back to your code: Need to test!
Note the brackets around the conditions and the use of `and`
[*Updated: realised I posted the wrong code snippet*]

```py
# To write your logic here
# First, define leap year
### divisible by 4 and if divisible by 100, also divisible by 400
# Work out the logic and then write the code

def is_leap(year): 
    ## set leap default to false
    leap = False

    ## leap condition
    ## divisible by 4 except if divisible by 100 but not divisible by 400, return true (as leap year)
    ## the `and not` implies 'except'
    if (year%4 == 0) and not (year%400 != 0 and year%100 == 0):
        return True
    else:
        return False
    return leap

'''
## Note that we can follow the flowchart testing for 4, except (100 and not 400)
## Possible one-liner
    return (year % 4 == 0) and not (year % 100 == 0 and year % 400 != 0)
'''

year = int(input()) 
#year2 = 1900 #test
print(f'{year2} is leap year: {is_leap(year2)}')
```